# TPS564247 switching voltage regulator problem

Tags: voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, switching-regulator, texas-instruments

I have been working on a 12 V to 3.3 V DCDC converter that uses the [TPS564247](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps564247.pdf) switching regulator IC. Here is the schematic:

[image]

The problem is that the IC keeps resetting itself once a second. At first, I measured 12 V on the 3.3 V rail but nothing shorted the two power rails together. Then I replaced the IC with a new one, and now it is resetting faster, around twice a second. Now, I also hear a little noise from the inductor when it tries to turn on. Should I look for soldering issues or maybe redo something in the schematic?

Comment: Have you made a PCB or working in a breadboard?

Comment: Zener diode voltage?

Comment: I once had a board where the inductor was soldered 90 degrees rotated.  For a square inductor it looks OK but if course it's a dead short.   Can you please show the layout also?

Comment: Is it "resetting" at full load?  Your inductor looks undersized for 4 A continuous load.

Comment: I got a whiff of a broken feedback path.

Comment: what is the load?

Comment: Nope, this occurs with no load.

Comment: I reflowed the PCB, and the pulsing is gone thankfully. Now, the voltage is around 7.5 V and the reference is around 1.6 V.

Comment: Try adding a small load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: It is working now flawlessly. Some legs did not touch the pads on the PCB so some rework fixed the circuit.